# How to execute and return value form a stored procedure inside FluentNHibernate Mapping?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, nhibernate

Well, I have a `ClassMap` like this for my mapping in `FluentNHibernate`

```
public class AbNopCommereceMap : ClassMap<AbNopCommerece>
{
    public AbNopCommereceMap()
    {
        Table("AbNopCommerece");
        Id(d => d.Id).CustomSqlType("BIGINT").GeneratedBy.Native();

        Map(d => d.Name).CustomSqlType("NVARCHAR(100)").Unique().Not.Nullable();    

        Map(u => u.PublisherName);
        Map(u => u.Author);
        Map(u => u.Country);
        Map(u => u.LastModifiedByFullName).Formula("(SELECT b.FirstName +' '+ b.LastName FROM Users b WHERE b.Id=CreatedBy)");

        Map(d => d.IsActive);
        Map(d => d.IsDeleted);
        Map(d => d.IsLocked);
        Map(d => d.CreatedBy).CustomType<TypedAggregateReferenceType<User>>();
        Map(d => d.CreatedByDate);
        Map(d => d.LastModifiedBy).CustomType<TypedAggregateReferenceType<User>>();
        Map(d => d.LastModifiedByDate);
        Map(d => d.Organization).Column("OrganizationId").CustomType<TypedAggregateReferenceType<Organization>>();
        Cache.Region("General").NonStrictReadWrite();
        ApplyFilter<OrganizationFilter>();
    }
}
```

Here `LastModifiedByFullName` is my User which I am selecting from the database, I want to execute a stored procedure here which I have already in my SQL server like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pop_use(@id int) 
as
DECLARE @FullName NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @FullName = ''
SELECT @FullName = FirstName + ' '+ LastName FROM Users WHERE Id = @UserId
```

I have gone through this [question1](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37425/Execute-Stored-Procedure-in-SQL-Server-using-nHibe), [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091521/how-do-i-call-a-stored-procedure-from-nhibernate-that-has-no-result) but they have used made a new function or XML to retrieve the value from data base. So, my question is, as I `NHibernate` has already provide some feature like `Format` by which I am getting the value from database directly, therefore is there any way in ClassMap to execute the `stored Procedure` and let not me do  some repetitive code again inside `ClassMap`. In a word I am seeking for any way to collect the data from database through previously defined particular store procedure and add it into model.

Comment: Did you see this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/278807/1162077). Suggests it might be possible using `Formula()`.

Answer (score 2):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12900448/6666799), you can't use a stored procedure in a `Select`, `Where` or `Having` statement, you need to use a function that returns a value.

```
CREATE FUNCTION pop_use(@UserId int) 
as
DECLARE @FullName NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @FullName = ''
SELECT @FullName = FirstName + ' '+ LastName FROM Users WHERE Id = @UserId
Return(@FullName)
```

Then you can use your function

```
Map(u => u.LastModifiedByFullName).Formula("mySchema.pop_use(myIdColumnName)");
```

`myIdColumnName` is the name of your identifier.
Please note that you must specify your schema in the function call.

You can take a look to [Ayende](https://ayende.com/blog/1720/using-sql-functions-in-nhibernate), he gives you a example how to use a function in a formula.

Kudos to [Frédéric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1178314) for his valuable input.

Comment: @ShoumenAgdm Please show us what you tried. It's definitely working. We uses this in multiple mappings.

Comment: Look on my [StoredProcedure](http://imgur.com/a/99o4h) 
My [C# COde](http://imgur.com/a/MeS49)
Let's enjoy the [error](http://imgur.com/a/jrDQw)

Comment: @ShoumenAgdm i compared your code with mine and the only difference i could find was that you use a `Procedure` and we use `Function`. Can you change it to a function? The difference between the two is stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1179778/6666799) and it looks that you can easily use a function instead.

Comment: Look I have made a function now [link](http://imgur.com/a/1DrIq), invoked it, but still not working.

Comment: @ShoumenAgdm 1. Did you tried your function by hand? 2. And did you tried to specifiy the schema on calling it like i suggested? 3. Do you get any exceptions while executing a query to the Database? 4. Do you have the possibility to look at the generated sql from NHibernate? If not, i would suggest to use [NhProfiler](https://hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof), its free for 30 days, so give it a try.

Comment: 1. Yes, I did tried by hand. 2. Yes. 3. No, I didn't got exception. 4. Exception is coming before the execution in the mapping. Anyway I am trying the link you provided. Good day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137015/discussion-between-shoumen-agdm-and-rabban).